# Journey Builder Open rate 200%

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

How is this possible?  Looks like one of the sends wasn't tracked?

[image]

Comment: You should celebrate. Your engagement has gone through the roof ;)

Comment: That caaaant be it.

Comment: Email was forwarded or sent to an alias?

Comment: Could the tracking code/pixel be inserted twice in the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of data lag on the marketing Cloud side.  Depending on the complexity of your journey/email send, you should wait at least an hour for results to normalize.